# Chat app setValue at x failed: DatabaseError:

Tags: android, firebase

I have a chat app, and every time I attempt to type a message I get an error such as this:

> W/RepoOperation: setValue at /-LLExyceqnVtrlDcS_a failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

I saw that it was a Firebase Database config error, so I've gone in and set it to the test settings:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

However the error keeps happening. All the other solutions seem to have outdated code.

Here's the method that triggers it:

```
   private void displayChat() {

        ListView listOfMessage = findViewById(R.id.list_of_message);

        Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        FirebaseListOptions<Chat> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<Chat>()
                .setLayout(R.layout.list_item)
                .setQuery(query, Chat.class)
                .build();

        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chat>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Chat model, int position) {
                //Get reference to the views of list_item.xml
                TextView messageText, messageUser, messageTime;
                messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)", model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };
        listOfMessage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you are receiving this error becasue your rules are  not equal to null. which means nobody can read and write data from/to your fireabase database until and unless he/she get the instance of authentication.[Read about Auth Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/)

[image: Rule]

lets say if you don't want your user to be authenticated then update these rules as `auth == null` for both read and write

hope this is helping